# Macos Podman Minikube setup, anyone have it working? I end up with errors connecting via ssh

Tags: macos, minikube, podman

I've spent days looking into this, most of the suggestions being just 'do a minikube delete' which doesn't help at all. I've tried reinstalling podman and minikube both wiping the config dirs as well. I can get this running just fine on a linux box, but unfortunately I have to get this working on macos as well.

My guess is that the ssh calls aren't being routed properly to the minikube container, and that has something to do with the 'no such network' message in the logs.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction debug wise?

podman machine init (vars are derived from the system info calculated by a bash script)

```
podman machine init --cpu $CPU --memory $MEMORY
```

podman machine running:

```
podman-machine-default  qemu        3 hours ago  Currently running  14          17.18GB     10.74GB
```

minikube start command:

```
 minikube start --cpus=4 --memory="8GB" --disk-size 100GB --wait=all --wait-timeout=30m0s --driver=podman --alsologtostderr
```

logs:

```
I0215 17:12:46.688961    7783 out.go:297] Setting OutFile to fd 1 ...
I0215 17:12:46.689155    7783 out.go:349] isatty.IsTerminal(1) = true
I0215 17:12:46.689163    7783 out.go:310] Setting ErrFile to fd 2...
I0215 17:12:46.689168    7783 out.go:349] isatty.IsTerminal(2) = true
I0215 17:12:46.689256    7783 root.go:313] Updating PATH: /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/bin
I0215 17:12:46.689626    7783 out.go:304] Setting JSON to false
I0215 17:12:46.735063    7783 start.go:112] hostinfo: {"hostname":"MGC12D93X6MD6R.fbpld77.ford.com","uptime":12801,"bootTime":1644950365,"procs":451,"os":"darwin","platform":"darwin","platformFamily":"Standalone Workstation","platformVersion":"11.5.2","kernelVersion":"20.6.0","kernelArch":"x86_64","virtualizationSystem":"","virtualizationRole":"","hostId":"c10f3eab-7543-504c-9b8e-f4022d860bbe"}
W0215 17:12:46.735220    7783 start.go:120] gopshost.Virtualization returned error: not implemented yet
I0215 17:12:46.755846    7783 out.go:176]   minikube v1.24.0 on Darwin 11.5.2
  minikube v1.24.0 on Darwin 11.5.2
I0215 17:12:46.756025    7783 notify.go:174] Checking for updates...
I0215 17:12:46.756376    7783 driver.go:343] Setting default libvirt URI to qemu:///system
I0215 17:12:47.005804    7783 podman.go:121] podman version: 3.4.4
I0215 17:12:47.025516    7783 out.go:176] ✨  Using the podman (experimental) driver based on user configuration
✨  Using the podman (experimental) driver based on user configuration
I0215 17:12:47.025541    7783 start.go:280] selected driver: podman
I0215 17:12:47.025550    7783 start.go:762] validating driver "podman" against <nil>
I0215 17:12:47.025570    7783 start.go:773] status for podman: {Installed:true Healthy:true Running:false NeedsImprovement:false Error:<nil> Reason: Fix: Doc:}
I0215 17:12:47.025739    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman system info --format json
I0215 17:12:47.230347    7783 info.go:285] podman info: {Host:{BuildahVersion:1.23.1 CgroupVersion:v2 Conmon:{Package:conmon-2.1.0-2.fc35.x86_64 Path:/usr/bin/conmon Version:conmon version 2.1.0, commit: } Distribution:{Distribution:fedora Version:35} MemFree:13495173120 MemTotal:16765710336 OCIRuntime:{Name:crun Package:crun-1.4.2-1.fc35.x86_64 Path:/usr/bin/crun Version:crun version 1.4.2
commit: f6fbc8f840df1a414f31a60953ae514fa497c748
spec: 1.0.0
+SYSTEMD +SELINUX +APPARMOR +CAP +SECCOMP +EBPF +CRIU +YAJL} SwapFree:0 SwapTotal:0 Arch:amd64 Cpus:14 Eventlogger:journald Hostname:localhost.localdomain Kernel:5.15.18-200.fc35.x86_64 Os:linux Rootless:false Uptime:3h 6m 45.7s (Approximately 0.12 days)} Registries:{Search:[docker.io]} Store:{ConfigFile:/etc/containers/storage.conf ContainerStore:{Number:0} GraphDriverName:overlay GraphOptions:{} GraphRoot:/var/lib/containers/storage GraphStatus:{BackingFilesystem:xfs NativeOverlayDiff:false SupportsDType:true UsingMetacopy:true} ImageStore:{Number:1} RunRoot:/run/containers/storage VolumePath:/var/lib/containers/storage/volumes}}
I0215 17:12:47.233207    7783 start_flags.go:268] no existing cluster config was found, will generate one from the flags 
I0215 17:12:47.233404    7783 start_flags.go:754] Waiting for all components: map[apiserver:true apps_running:true default_sa:true extra:true kubelet:true node_ready:true system_pods:true]
I0215 17:12:47.233453    7783 cni.go:93] Creating CNI manager for ""
I0215 17:12:47.233460    7783 cni.go:167] CNI unnecessary in this configuration, recommending no CNI
I0215 17:12:47.233473    7783 start_flags.go:282] config:
{Name:minikube KeepContext:false EmbedCerts:false MinikubeISO: KicBaseImage:gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28@sha256:4780f1897569d2bf77aafb3d133a08d42b4fe61127f06fcfc90c2c5d902d893c Memory:8192 CPUs:4 DiskSize:102400 VMDriver: Driver:podman HyperkitVpnKitSock: HyperkitVSockPorts:[] DockerEnv:[] ContainerVolumeMounts:[] InsecureRegistry:[] RegistryMirror:[] HostOnlyCIDR:192.168.59.1/24 HypervVirtualSwitch: HypervUseExternalSwitch:false HypervExternalAdapter: KVMNetwork:default KVMQemuURI:qemu:///system KVMGPU:false KVMHidden:false KVMNUMACount:1 DockerOpt:[] DisableDriverMounts:false NFSShare:[] NFSSharesRoot:/nfsshares UUID: NoVTXCheck:false DNSProxy:false HostDNSResolver:true HostOnlyNicType:virtio NatNicType:virtio SSHIPAddress: SSHUser:root SSHKey: SSHPort:22 KubernetesConfig:{KubernetesVersion:v1.22.3 ClusterName:minikube Namespace:default APIServerName:minikubeCA APIServerNames:[] APIServerIPs:[] DNSDomain:cluster.local ContainerRuntime:docker CRISocket: NetworkPlugin: FeatureGates: ServiceCIDR:10.96.0.0/12 ImageRepository: LoadBalancerStartIP: LoadBalancerEndIP: CustomIngressCert: ExtraOptions:[] ShouldLoadCachedImages:true EnableDefaultCNI:false CNI: NodeIP: NodePort:8443 NodeName:} Nodes:[] Addons:map[] CustomAddonImages:map[] CustomAddonRegistries:map[] VerifyComponents:map[apiserver:true apps_running:true default_sa:true extra:true kubelet:true node_ready:true system_pods:true] StartHostTimeout:30m0s ScheduledStop:<nil> ExposedPorts:[] ListenAddress: Network: MultiNodeRequested:false ExtraDisks:0 CertExpiration:26280h0m0s Mount:false MountString:/Users:/minikube-host}
I0215 17:12:47.270914    7783 out.go:176]   Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
I0215 17:12:47.270987    7783 cache.go:118] Beginning downloading kic base image for podman with docker
I0215 17:12:47.289875    7783 out.go:176]   Pulling base image ...
  Pulling base image ...
I0215 17:12:47.290010    7783 preload.go:132] Checking if preload exists for k8s version v1.22.3 and runtime docker
I0215 17:12:47.290077    7783 cache.go:146] Downloading gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28@sha256:4780f1897569d2bf77aafb3d133a08d42b4fe61127f06fcfc90c2c5d902d893c to local cache
I0215 17:12:47.290131    7783 preload.go:148] Found local preload: /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/cache/preloaded-tarball/preloaded-images-k8s-v13-v1.22.3-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4
I0215 17:12:47.290165    7783 cache.go:57] Caching tarball of preloaded images
I0215 17:12:47.290352    7783 image.go:59] Checking for gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28@sha256:4780f1897569d2bf77aafb3d133a08d42b4fe61127f06fcfc90c2c5d902d893c in local cache directory
I0215 17:12:47.290400    7783 preload.go:174] Found /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/cache/preloaded-tarball/preloaded-images-k8s-v13-v1.22.3-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4 in cache, skipping download
I0215 17:12:47.290402    7783 image.go:62] Found gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28@sha256:4780f1897569d2bf77aafb3d133a08d42b4fe61127f06fcfc90c2c5d902d893c in local cache directory, skipping pull
I0215 17:12:47.290439    7783 image.go:103] gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28@sha256:4780f1897569d2bf77aafb3d133a08d42b4fe61127f06fcfc90c2c5d902d893c exists in cache, skipping pull
I0215 17:12:47.290454    7783 cache.go:60] Finished verifying existence of preloaded tar for  v1.22.3 on docker
I0215 17:12:47.290477    7783 cache.go:149] successfully saved gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28@sha256:4780f1897569d2bf77aafb3d133a08d42b4fe61127f06fcfc90c2c5d902d893c as a tarball
I0215 17:12:47.290917    7783 profile.go:147] Saving config to /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/profiles/minikube/config.json ...
I0215 17:12:47.290947    7783 lock.go:35] WriteFile acquiring /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/profiles/minikube/config.json: {Name:mk1b4df0865662d5873b3763b81d8aab8be0eabe Clock:{} Delay:500ms Timeout:1m0s Cancel:<nil>}
E0215 17:12:47.291553    7783 cache.go:201] Error downloading kic artifacts:  not yet implemented, see issue #8426
I0215 17:12:47.291562    7783 cache.go:206] Successfully downloaded all kic artifacts
I0215 17:12:47.291589    7783 start.go:313] acquiring machines lock for minikube: {Name:mk96344c390830e0b2d6941cbae4706a1f8bae17 Clock:{} Delay:500ms Timeout:10m0s Cancel:<nil>}
I0215 17:12:47.291644    7783 start.go:317] acquired machines lock for "minikube" in 47.398µs
I0215 17:12:47.291697    7783 start.go:89] Provisioning new machine with config: &{Name:minikube KeepContext:false EmbedCerts:false MinikubeISO: KicBaseImage:gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28@sha256:4780f1897569d2bf77aafb3d133a08d42b4fe61127f06fcfc90c2c5d902d893c Memory:8192 CPUs:4 DiskSize:102400 VMDriver: Driver:podman HyperkitVpnKitSock: HyperkitVSockPorts:[] DockerEnv:[] ContainerVolumeMounts:[] InsecureRegistry:[] RegistryMirror:[] HostOnlyCIDR:192.168.59.1/24 HypervVirtualSwitch: HypervUseExternalSwitch:false HypervExternalAdapter: KVMNetwork:default KVMQemuURI:qemu:///system KVMGPU:false KVMHidden:false KVMNUMACount:1 DockerOpt:[] DisableDriverMounts:false NFSShare:[] NFSSharesRoot:/nfsshares UUID: NoVTXCheck:false DNSProxy:false HostDNSResolver:true HostOnlyNicType:virtio NatNicType:virtio SSHIPAddress: SSHUser:root SSHKey: SSHPort:22 KubernetesConfig:{KubernetesVersion:v1.22.3 ClusterName:minikube Namespace:default APIServerName:minikubeCA APIServerNames:[] APIServerIPs:[] DNSDomain:cluster.local ContainerRuntime:docker CRISocket: NetworkPlugin: FeatureGates: ServiceCIDR:10.96.0.0/12 ImageRepository: LoadBalancerStartIP: LoadBalancerEndIP: CustomIngressCert: ExtraOptions:[] ShouldLoadCachedImages:true EnableDefaultCNI:false CNI: NodeIP: NodePort:8443 NodeName:} Nodes:[{Name: IP: Port:8443 KubernetesVersion:v1.22.3 ControlPlane:true Worker:true}] Addons:map[] CustomAddonImages:map[] CustomAddonRegistries:map[] VerifyComponents:map[apiserver:true apps_running:true default_sa:true extra:true kubelet:true node_ready:true system_pods:true] StartHostTimeout:30m0s ScheduledStop:<nil> ExposedPorts:[] ListenAddress: Network: MultiNodeRequested:false ExtraDisks:0 CertExpiration:26280h0m0s Mount:false MountString:/Users:/minikube-host} &{Name: IP: Port:8443 KubernetesVersion:v1.22.3 ControlPlane:true Worker:true}
I0215 17:12:47.291832    7783 start.go:126] createHost starting for "" (driver="podman")
I0215 17:12:47.329349    7783 out.go:203]   Creating podman container (CPUs=4, Memory=8192MB) ...
  Creating podman container (CPUs=4, Memory=8192MB) ...| I0215 17:12:47.329683    7783 start.go:160] libmachine.API.Create for "minikube" (driver="podman")
I0215 17:12:47.329733    7783 client.go:168] LocalClient.Create starting
I0215 17:12:47.329901    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Reading certificate data from /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/certs/ca.pem
I0215 17:12:47.329971    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Decoding PEM data...
I0215 17:12:47.329990    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Parsing certificate...
I0215 17:12:47.330085    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Reading certificate data from /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/certs/cert.pem
I0215 17:12:47.330140    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Decoding PEM data...
I0215 17:12:47.330151    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Parsing certificate...
I0215 17:12:47.331042    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman network inspect minikube --format "{{range .plugins}}{{if eq .type "bridge"}}{{(index (index .ipam.ranges 0) 0).subnet}},{{(index (index .ipam.ranges 0) 0).gateway}}{{end}}{{end}}"
/ W0215 17:12:47.500272    7783 cli_runner.go:162] podman network inspect minikube --format "{{range .plugins}}{{if eq .type "bridge"}}{{(index (index .ipam.ranges 0) 0).subnet}},{{(index (index .ipam.ranges 0) 0).gateway}}{{end}}{{end}}" returned with exit code 125
I0215 17:12:47.500405    7783 network_create.go:254] running [podman network inspect minikube] to gather additional debugging logs...
I0215 17:12:47.500430    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman network inspect minikube
\ W0215 17:12:47.669206    7783 cli_runner.go:162] podman network inspect minikube returned with exit code 125
I0215 17:12:47.669240    7783 network_create.go:257] error running [podman network inspect minikube]: podman network inspect minikube: exit status 125
stdout:
[]

stderr:
Error: error inspecting object: no such network "minikube"
I0215 17:12:47.669266    7783 network_create.go:259] output of [podman network inspect minikube]: -- stdout --
[]

-- /stdout --
** stderr ** 
Error: error inspecting object: no such network "minikube"

** /stderr **
I0215 17:12:47.669341    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman network inspect podman --format "{{range .plugins}}{{if eq .type "bridge"}}{{(index (index .ipam.ranges 0) 0).subnet}},{{(index (index .ipam.ranges 0) 0).gateway}}{{end}}{{end}}"
/ I0215 17:12:47.841466    7783 network.go:288] reserving subnet 192.168.49.0 for 1m0s: &{mu:{state:0 sema:0} read:{v:{m:map[] amended:true}} dirty:map[192.168.49.0:0xc00000e0a8] misses:0}
I0215 17:12:47.841512    7783 network.go:235] using free private subnet 192.168.49.0/24: &{IP:192.168.49.0 Netmask:255.255.255.0 Prefix:24 CIDR:192.168.49.0/24 Gateway:192.168.49.1 ClientMin:192.168.49.2 ClientMax:192.168.49.254 Broadcast:192.168.49.255 Interface:{IfaceName: IfaceIPv4: IfaceMTU:0 IfaceMAC:}}
I0215 17:12:47.841528    7783 network_create.go:106] attempt to create podman network minikube 192.168.49.0/24 with gateway 192.168.49.1 and MTU of 0 ...
I0215 17:12:47.841610    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.49.0/24 --gateway=192.168.49.1 --label=created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=true minikube
- I0215 17:12:48.012067    7783 network_create.go:90] podman network minikube 192.168.49.0/24 created
I0215 17:12:48.012106    7783 kic.go:106] calculated static IP "192.168.49.2" for the "minikube" container
I0215 17:12:48.012272    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman ps -a --format {{.Names}}
| I0215 17:12:48.182356    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman volume create minikube --label name.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --label created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=true
- I0215 17:12:48.353886    7783 oci.go:102] Successfully created a podman volume minikube
I0215 17:12:48.354001    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman run --rm --name minikube-preload-sidecar --label created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=true --label name.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --entrypoint /usr/bin/test -v minikube:/var gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28 -d /var/lib
- I0215 17:12:49.614378    7783 cli_runner.go:168] Completed: podman run --rm --name minikube-preload-sidecar --label created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=true --label name.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --entrypoint /usr/bin/test -v minikube:/var gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28 -d /var/lib: (1.260310912s)
I0215 17:12:49.614408    7783 oci.go:106] Successfully prepared a podman volume minikube
I0215 17:12:49.614458    7783 preload.go:132] Checking if preload exists for k8s version v1.22.3 and runtime docker
I0215 17:12:49.614474    7783 kic.go:179] Starting extracting preloaded images to volume ...
I0215 17:12:49.614505    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman info --format "'{{json .SecurityOptions}}'"
I0215 17:12:49.614603    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman run --rm --entrypoint /usr/bin/tar -v /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/cache/preloaded-tarball/preloaded-images-k8s-v13-v1.22.3-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4:/preloaded.tar:ro -v minikube:/extractDir gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28 -I lz4 -xf /preloaded.tar -C /extractDir
/ W0215 17:12:49.895058    7783 cli_runner.go:162] podman info --format "'{{json .SecurityOptions}}'" returned with exit code 125
I0215 17:12:49.895243    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman run -d -t --privileged --device /dev/fuse --security-opt seccomp=unconfined --tmpfs /tmp --tmpfs /run -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro --hostname minikube --name minikube --label created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=true --label name.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --label role.minikube.sigs.k8s.io= --label mode.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --network minikube --ip 192.168.49.2 --volume minikube:/var:exec --memory-swap=8192mb --memory=8192mb --cpus=4 -e container=podman --expose 8443 --publish=127.0.0.1::8443 --publish=127.0.0.1::22 --publish=127.0.0.1::2376 --publish=127.0.0.1::5000 --publish=127.0.0.1::32443 gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28
W0215 17:12:49.937799    7783 cli_runner.go:162] podman run --rm --entrypoint /usr/bin/tar -v /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/cache/preloaded-tarball/preloaded-images-k8s-v13-v1.22.3-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4:/preloaded.tar:ro -v minikube:/extractDir gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28 -I lz4 -xf /preloaded.tar -C /extractDir returned with exit code 125
I0215 17:12:49.937856    7783 kic.go:186] Unable to extract preloaded tarball to volume: podman run --rm --entrypoint /usr/bin/tar -v /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/cache/preloaded-tarball/preloaded-images-k8s-v13-v1.22.3-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4:/preloaded.tar:ro -v minikube:/extractDir gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.28 -I lz4 -xf /preloaded.tar -C /extractDir: exit status 125
stdout:

stderr:
Error: statfs /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/cache/preloaded-tarball/preloaded-images-k8s-v13-v1.22.3-docker-overlay2-amd64.tar.lz4: no such file or directory
| I0215 17:12:50.626660    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Running}}
- I0215 17:12:50.908780    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}
/ I0215 17:12:51.156225    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman exec minikube stat /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/iptables
| I0215 17:12:51.543705    7783 oci.go:281] the created container "minikube" has a running status.
I0215 17:12:51.543741    7783 kic.go:210] Creating ssh key for kic: /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa...
- I0215 17:12:51.736702    7783 kic_runner.go:187] podman (temp): /Users/gdittri1/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa.pub --> /home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys (381 bytes)
I0215 17:12:51.740282    7783 kic_runner.go:272] Run: /usr/local/bin/podman exec -i minikube tee /home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys
- I0215 17:12:52.133720    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}
| I0215 17:12:52.356034    7783 kic_runner.go:93] Run: chown docker:docker /home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys
I0215 17:12:52.356101    7783 kic_runner.go:114] Args: [podman exec --privileged minikube chown docker:docker /home/docker/.ssh/authorized_keys]
\ I0215 17:12:52.638946    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman container inspect minikube --format={{.State.Status}}
/ I0215 17:12:52.833654    7783 machine.go:88] provisioning docker machine ...
I0215 17:12:52.833734    7783 ubuntu.go:169] provisioning hostname "minikube"
I0215 17:12:52.833863    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman version --format {{.Version}}
| I0215 17:12:53.093665    7783 cli_runner.go:115] Run: podman container inspect -f "'{{(index (index .NetworkSettings.Ports "22/tcp") 0).HostPort}}'" minikube
/ I0215 17:12:53.290195    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Using SSH client type: native
I0215 17:12:53.290458    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: &{{{<nil> 0 [] [] []} docker [0x1396ec0] 0x1399fa0 <nil>  [] 0s} 127.0.0.1 36327 <nil> <nil>}
I0215 17:12:53.290476    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: About to run SSH command:
sudo hostname minikube && echo "minikube" | sudo tee /etc/hostname
I0215 17:12:53.291434    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58149->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
\ I0215 17:12:56.293911    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58150->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
| I0215 17:12:59.296215    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58151->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
/ I0215 17:13:02.300200    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58152->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
- I0215 17:13:05.304566    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58153->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
| I0215 17:13:08.307108    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58154->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
/ I0215 17:13:11.309256    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58155->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
- I0215 17:13:14.312617    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58156->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
\ I0215 17:13:17.317423    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58157->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
/ I0215 17:13:20.321361    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58158->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
- I0215 17:13:23.327387    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58159->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
\ I0215 17:13:26.331340    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58160->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
/ I0215 17:13:29.333104    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58161->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
- I0215 17:13:32.337739    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58162->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
\ I0215 17:13:35.340744    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58163->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
| I0215 17:13:38.343365    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58164->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
- I0215 17:13:41.347142    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58165->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
\ I0215 17:13:44.350661    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58166->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
| I0215 17:13:47.353094    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58167->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
- I0215 17:13:50.354277    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58168->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
\ I0215 17:13:53.357716    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58169->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
| I0215 17:13:56.361216    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58170->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
/ I0215 17:13:59.365807    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58171->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
\ I0215 17:14:02.367380    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58172->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
| I0215 17:14:05.373500    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58173->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
/ I0215 17:14:08.376993    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58174->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
\ I0215 17:14:11.381381    7783 main.go:130] libmachine: Error dialing TCP: ssh: handshake failed: read tcp 127.0.0.1:58175->127.0.0.1:36327: read: connection reset by peer
| I
```

Edit #1: Looks like if i manually try to create the minikube network
`podman network create minikube` it fails with

```
Resolving "network" using unqualified-search registries (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/999-podman-machine.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/network:latest...
Error: initializing source docker://network:latest: reading manifest latest in docker.io/library/network: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
unauthorized: authentication required
```

I'm not sure why this is, I've verified i'm logged into dockerhub I can pull my private images from there just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to start minikube using podman with the following steps:

1. podman machine init --cpus 2 --memory 2048 --disk-size 20 --image-path next
2. podman machine start
3. podman system connection default podman-machine-default-root
4. minikube start --driver=podman --listen-address=192.168.127.2

Comment: Late response but did you even that? Minikube I believe requires at least 4gb of ram to even start